# angularjs build search criteria with check boxes

Tags: angularjs, search, checkbox

Forgive the noob angular question:

I am attempting to aggregate product search terms using check boxes.  When a user selects/deselects an check box, the values are returned and filter the product list...

My initial approach was to hard code the product categories and then run a ng-click function that iterated the categories and built the search string...  i.e.  (product=controllerAs syntax)

```
<input ng-click="product.changeSearch()" ng-model="product.criteria.form.liquid">
<input ng-click="product.changeSearch()" ng-model="product.criteria.form.solid">
```

Then on the controller side:

```
vm.changeSearch = function() {
_.map(vm.criteria.forms, function(criteria) {
        if (criteria) {
            criteriaCompiled.push(criteria);
        }

        console.log('criteria: ', criteriaCompiled);
    });
```

The ideal output would be "mongo-ready" such that I can run a find.{ form: "Liquid, form: "Solid" } query.

I'm thinking this is the wrong strategy because I have about 20 elements to choose from and the array is proving difficult to map and return meaningful values, especially when looking at true/false checkbox values...

Any practical or theoretical advise is appreciated...

Comment: checkboxes can have values also see checkbox docs for `ng-true-value` & `ng-false-value`etc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: @charlietfl thank you, this has worked great.  do you need to repost as answer so I can accept?